# iphone : How to get Address from json request?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, ipad

I am trying to get this address = "8198 Snouffer School Rd, Gaithersburg, MD 20879, USA"

from this json request but could not successful to do it.

```
{
  "name": "39.165110,-77.168550",
  "Status": {
    "code": 200,
    "request": "geocode"
  },
  "Placemark": [ {
    "id": "p1",
    "address": "8198 Snouffer School Rd, Gaithersburg, MD 20879, USA",
    "AddressDetails": {
   "Accuracy" : 8,
   "Country" : {
      "AdministrativeArea" : {
         "AdministrativeAreaName" : "MD",
         "Locality" : {
            "LocalityName" : "Gaithersburg",
            "PostalCode" : {
               "PostalCodeNumber" : "20879"
            },
            "Thoroughfare" : {
               "ThoroughfareName" : "Snouffer School Rd"
            }
         }
      },
      "CountryName" : "USA",
      "CountryNameCode" : "US"
   }
},
    "ExtendedData": {
      "LatLonBox": {
        "north": 39.1661825,
        "south": 39.1634846,
        "east": -77.1666884,
        "west": -77.1693864
      }
    },
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": [ -77.1685611, 39.1650977, 0 ]
    }
  } ]
}
```

I have extracted Code from status but could not understand how to extract address.

```
NSArray* Status = [(NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"Status"];

NSString *code = [Status objectForKey:@"code"];            
NSArray* Placemark  = [(NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"Placemark"];    
NSString *address = [Placemark objectForKey:@"address"]; // got error at this line.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an Array not the JSON Object.
try

```
NSString *address = [[Placemark objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"address"]];
```

Comment: Obviously, make sure that Placemark is not an empty array, and that the first element is an NSDictionary in your production code. I often use this macro: `#define SAFE_DICTIONARY(dict)   ([dict isKindOfClass: [NSDictionary class]] ? dict : nil)`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the placemark entry returns an array, not a dictionary (see the square brackets?).

PS: Please use small starting letters for your variables - otherwise they look like classes:-).

Answer (score 0):

@Azhar :- Try this -- id

i.e

id Status = [(NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"Status"];

id code = [Status objectForKey:@"code"];
id Placemark  = [(NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"Placemark"];
id address = [Placemark objectForKey:@"address"];

and find the desired key.